# In an iOS app, even when no main custom UIView is added, I can still add other view objects as subview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

It is quite strange that in some other iOS apps, I created a Single View app, and then added `MainView.h` and `MainView.m` that is the subclass of `UIView`, but then in another program, I didn't add such class, but could immediately do:

```
ShapeView *sv;

sv = [[ShapeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 170, 140, 140)];
[self.view addSubview:sv];
```

inside of `ViewController.m`.  Of course, `ShapeView.m` has to implement `drawRect` to properly draw the shape.  But how come we don't need to add a `MainView.h` and `MainView.m` first this time and still draw on some main view?

Comment: I could not understand please elaborate your problem.

Comment: I guess my question is: Why do we have to add `MainView.h` and `.m` for one app, but don't have to in another app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to add `MainView.h` and `.m` for any app. That is necessary only when you want your own customized `UIView` named "MainView". If you don't need to draw the view or part of the view yourself, view controller + XIB/NIB work well.

The main `UIViewController` in your app (which is created from Single View App template as you mentioned) creates a default `UIView` which is loaded from the default NIB/XIB. It is available as `self.view` in your `UIViewController` code after the view is loaded.

In fact `MainView` is nothing special compared with `ShapeView`. They are both customized `UIView` subclasses.